# ¿Como cambiar la disposición de los elementos en la resolución pequeña y mediana con Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap

**Un increíble saludo.**

Tengo este pie de pagina, pero en la versión extra-pequeña, pequeña y mediana, no se ve bien, por tanto me gustaría que el contenido en estas resoluciones, quede mejor centrado, ya que normalmente tengo el texto del footer justificado a los extremos, sin embargo no se en este caso que se puede hacer.
*(Lo estoy haciendo con Bootstrap).*

**Muchas gracias.**

```css
/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  background-color:#1A1A1A;
  height: 50%;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.main1 { 
  display:flex;
  margin:0 auto;
}

footer img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

footer img:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

```html
<!-- FOOTER -->  
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-left">
            <h6 class="text-muted lead">CONTACTO:</h6>
            <h6 class="text-muted">
            Carrera 8h No. 166-71 Local 2<br>
            Santa Cruz de la Ronda.<br>
            Teléfonos: 3115988953 – 3112641818.<br>
            </h6>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-right">
            <h6 class="text-muted lead">ENCUENTRANOS EN LAS REDES</h6>
            <div class="redes-footer">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="imagenes/facebook-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="imagenes/twitter-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="imagenes/youtube-2.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> 

        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <p class="text-muted small">José Miguel, arte y belleza @2016.<br> Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: En bootstrap y otras similares biene clases definidas para adaptar componentes acorde al tamaño del dispositivo; https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si trabajas con **bootstrap** y quieres que se comporte la visualización de manera *responsive* para tamaños pequeños creo que la clase a utilizar es "*col-sm-* *", así que debería quedarte las clases de los elementos *<div>* como:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 ...">
```

también podrías intentar probar a cambiar la clase "*container*" por "*container-fluid*" a ver si mejora la visualización.